# Chutzpah Unknown error occurred when executing test file. Received exit code of -1073741819

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs, chutzpah

I am using chutzpah 3.0.1 to run Jasmine JS unit tests.

However i am getting following error once all test completed and fails the build.

> "Unknown error occurred when executing test file. Received exit code of -1073741819"

When i am trying to run through command prompt after all tests run successfully i am getting following popup

[image]

I am using windows-8 64 bit. .Net 4.0

and following command used for commamd prompt execution

> chutzpah.console.exe "specRunner.html" /timeoutMilliseconds 60000

What could be an issue ? Is there any solution ?

Comment: Can you give a repro? And could this issue be related: https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/issues/219?

Comment: Thanks Matthew for u r reply...I referred u r link as well as https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/workitem/225 link which solves my problem

Comment: Hi Matthew, We split spec across multiple html files as per suggestion mentioned https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/workitem/225. Now how to get collective code coverage? We have only one source file and different spec.js according to module-wise. Also how to get code coverage for 'chutzpah.console.exe' 'specRunner.html'

Comment: I am not sure I follow your scenario. Please file a bug on the github page and provide a full repro

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/issues/389) on a github regarding this problem.
According to the link above one of the reasons for the problem is outdated version of Chutzpah CLI.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.